# Remove links in the navigation pane on the left in the ctrl+O menu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, filelink

[image: screenshot]

I accidently dragged a link into the pane on the left.
When I right click to remove the link, it is grayed out and I cannot select it.
How do I remove the link? (This is the ctrl+O menu, not normal window)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. Update: I reported it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1265418

As a workaround, edit the bookmark config file and delete the offending line:

```
nano -w ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```